# WPF Data binding and Image

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this Xaml code

```
<ListView x:Name="listOrderList" Margin="58,55,0,0" Background="{x:Null}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="DESCRIPTION" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="STATUS">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Status}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In C# I have an `enum` for Status and i know obviously `<Image Source="{Binding Status}"/>` is not going to work. But how can do something for example i have two values in `Status` enum. Say Yes and No. How can i assign small icons to enum's values and work with Bindings easily.

Thanks you.

Comment: Have a look at [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)

With that you can check which value was delivered by the binding and then create the `Image` object to display.

Answer (score 2):

Either you use a binding converter, or you add DataTriggers to your DataTemplate. The example below assumes the following enum

```
public enum Status { Status1, Status2 }
```

and sets the Image's `Source` property to different image resources depending on the value of the `Status` property.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="Image1" UriSource="..."/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="Image2" UriSource="..."/>
</Window.Resources>

...

<DataTemplate>
    <Image x:Name="image"/>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Status1">
            <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source"
                    Value="{StaticResource Image1}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Status2">
            <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source"
                    Value="{StaticResource Image2}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set Icon image path to Enum, then Bind DataGrid with that Enum.

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="colStatus" Width="160" Header="Status">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Width="135">
                                    <Image Height="14" Margin="2,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding Status}" Width="14" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```