# Adding different images to comboboxes depending on the binding values inside

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am pretty new to WPF and c#. I have coded out a simple form with a combo box and I have added an image to this combo box that will sit beside the text.  The image will change depending on the sex of the person class.

I just want to know if this is the correct practise for doing something like this or is there a better route I should be taking?

My Code is working as I want it too but I am concered I am learning bad practise.

I have used a separate property to determin the URL for the image it feels like this is not the best way to approach this kind of issue.

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Thanks,

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            people.Add(new Person { Firstname = "Sinead", Lastname = "McCoy" , Sex = "Female" });
            people.Add(new Person { Firstname = "Andrew", Lastname = "Warner", Sex = "Other" });
            people.Add(new Person { Firstname = "Ailish", Lastname = "Man" , Sex = "Female" });
            people.Add(new Person { Firstname = "Andrew", Lastname = "McCory", Sex = "Other" });
            people.Add(new Person { Firstname = "Andrew", Lastname = "McCall" , Sex = "Male" });


            //people.Add(a);
            cmbMyComboBox.ItemsSource = people;

        }
```

Below is my Person class:

```
class Person
{
    private string _sex;
    private string _cmbimage;
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Sex
    {
        get
        {
            var sex = new string[] { "Male", "Female" };

            if (sex.Contains(_sex))
            {
               return _sex;
            }
            else
                _sex = "Other";
                return _sex;
        }

        set
        {
                _sex = value;
        }
    }

    public string Fullname
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{Firstname} {Lastname}";
        }

    } 

    public string Cmbimage
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sex == "Male")
            {
                _cmbimage = "C:\\Users\\richa\\Pictures\\Icons\\WPFdemo\\cmbimage.png";
                return _cmbimage;
            }
            if (_sex == "Female")
            {
                _cmbimage = "C:\\Users\\richa\\Pictures\\Icons\\WPFdemo\\cmbimagegirl.png";
                return _cmbimage;
            }
            else
                _cmbimage = "C:\\Users\\richa\\Pictures\\Icons\\WPFdemo\\cmbimageother.png";
                return _cmbimage;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my Xaml for the combo box:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbMyComboBox" Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Cmbimage}" Height="20" Width="20"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Fullname}"/>
                    <!--<TextBlock Text=" "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lastname}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sex}"/>-->
                </StackPanel>                
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

EDIT:

```
   class Person
    {
        private Uri _cmbimage;


    public Uri Cmbimage
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sex == "Male")
            {
                _cmbimage = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/cmb_male.png");
                return _cmbimage;
            }
            if (_sex == "Female")
            {
                _cmbimage = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/cmb_female.png");
                return _cmbimage;
            }
            else
                _cmbimage = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/cmb_other.png");
                return _cmbimage;
        }
    }

}
```

DATA TRIGGER EDIT XAML:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="Image1" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Images/cmb_Male.png"/>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="Image2" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Images/cmb_Female.png"/>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="Image3" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Images/cmb_Other.png"/>
    </Window.Resources>


    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbMyComboBox" Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="image" Height="20" Width="20"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Fullname}"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <DataTemplate.Triggers>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Sex}" Value="Male">
                        <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source"
                             Value="{StaticResource Image1}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Sex}" Value="Female">
                        <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source"
                            Value="{StaticResource Image2}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Sex}" Value="Other">
                        <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Source"
                             Value="{StaticResource Image3}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>

                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: This approach is perfectly valid. I would however suggest not to load images from absolute file paths, but instead add the image files to your Visual Studio project and load them from [Resource File Pack URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf) like `pack://application:,,,/cmbimage.png`.

Comment: An alternative to a dedicated image path/URL property would be a set of DataTriggers on the Sex property, with Setters for the Image's Source property. like e.g. this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19226841/1136211

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for the tip - I made the edit in my code for the URI route.  The DataTrigger route I havent quite got it figured out yet never used xaml before so there is a little learning curve here.  Is there any major benifets of using the datatrigger instead? ill be honest it is more in line with how I would expect to solve this issue.

Comment: With DataTriggers you wouldn't have the Cmbimage at all, hence no explicitly defined images for the different sex values. Different views could use different images. As a note, your current Cmbimage implementation looks odd. It assigns a value to a `_cmbimage` field that is never used except as return value in the property getter. You should drop that field.

Comment: @Clemens I have managed to get the Triggers to work (see edit) but I cant seem to work out how to get my layout right.  With the ` StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal` this allowed the image then text to be displayed next to it easily. Is there a trick I am missing here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Why did you remove the StackPanel?

Comment: @Clemens I was slightly misunderstanding what the data trigger was doing. It just clicked and it was pretty obvious - This was how I was expecting to solve this one but couldn’t quite find the correct information which is why I went down setting the property route. Not quite decided which is easier to read and understand yet but knowing two routes is always better than one.  You have been very helpful thank you